# Using data bindings in Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have a problem using viewmodel in fragment with data binding.
In my programm i'm using only one activity and fragments. I organized transitions between fragments using navigation. And i want to use data binding in my fragment, but when running the application only with binding, everything works well when I pass to the binding viewmodel when switching to this fragment of the application, it crashes.

I would be very grateful for your help!

My fragment

```
class TimeSettings : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: TimeSettingsViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTimeSettingsBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentTimeSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewmodel = viewModel;
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Object for viewmodel

```
object TimeData {
    var inhale: Int = 4
    private val _currentTimeInhale = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val currentTimeInhale: LiveData<Int>
        get() = _currentTimeInhale
    init{
        _currentTimeInhale.value = inhale
    }
    fun changeCurrentTimeInhale(){
        _currentTimeInhale.value = 5
    }
}
```

Viewmodel

```
class TimeSettingsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val currentInhale: LiveData<Int>
        get() = TimeData.currentTimeInhale
    fun onChange() = TimeData.changeCurrentTimeInhale()
}
```

xml file for fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="ivakin.first.my_first_app.viewmodels.TimeSettingsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.currentInhale}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onChange()"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

U Forgot Initialize ViewModel :

```
viewmodel = TimeSettingsViewModel()
```

Also dont use `return binding.root`

Comment: What to use instead of binding.root?

Comment: The question here why we use binding.root?? getRoot() method in the FragmentTimeSettingBinding class returns the LinearLayout root view.

Comment: And here we want to use Viewmodel view so we just delete it and don't use it

Comment: And the answer we use nothing instead binding.viewmodel = viewmodel replace it

Comment: So, what should i return in onCreateView, because this method must return some view type?

Comment: I'm so sorry , I'm wrong . In ur example just keep return binding.root, The only mistake u have in your code was u didnt Initialize ViewModel

Comment: Again Im so sorry to u and @nitinkumarp